# Unable to create prod build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using [ion-simple-wizard](https://github.com/JoxieMedina/ionic2-simple-conditional-wizard) and few animations are used in it, which are restricting to create build in prod environment and throwing error:

```
build prod failed: dirMeta.animations.map is not a function
```

Its working fine in dev environment.

Comment: Have you tried the workarounds provided at this github thread? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3280

Comment: In which file you're facing the issue?

Comment: the link you provided has nothing to do with my code @unitario

Comment: I think it has everything to do with your code.

Comment: @Rohit file is "ion-simple-wizard-animations.ts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue. Use the animation function directly to your component file. Like I used this code in my component.

```
animations: [
    trigger('WizardAnimations', [
        state('enter', style({ position: 'absolute', top: 0 ,width:'100%'})),
        state('leave', style({ visibility: 'hidden', position: 'absolute', top: 0 })),
        transition('*=>enter', [
            style({visibility: 'visible', opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0)' }),
            animate('300ms ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'scale(1)' ,top: 0 }))
        ]),
        transition('*=>leave', [
            animate('300ms ease-out', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0)',top: 0  }))
        ])
    ])
]//TO DO: Change the animation by @Input for example
```

All the best (y)